# Reverse breakdown voltage over series elements

Tags: voltage, mosfet, schottky, reverse-breakdown

The M2* FETs are 100 V graded while D_pass is 150 V.

Will the FETs' body diodes help them survive a negative 150 V spike?

[image]

Comment: Under what condition? Like, it's forward-biased in normal operation, then suddenly reversed?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, let's say 15V on source pin

Comment: 15V on source...when? And what then? How fast? At what source impedance? What load---well, 5A or so, but is that maximum load or what?

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh, sorry. 12V at initial time. Then -150V over 1us spike comes along @ 10 ohm. Load will fluctuate between 2A and maybe 30A (transitory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

150V from 10Ω is a peak 15A. Unless your gate drive (say it's a protection circuit) responds as quickly, the pulse skates right on through, superimposed on load current; indeed, drain current might not reverse at all due to such pulse, given the load current range.

More likely the diode switches off (when I_L < 15A). STPS60150CT is a schottky diode, meaning it has no reverse recovery, only capacitance. (Actually, I bet it does have a little recovery, but not in the usual way, and still far less than a PN type.)